# Where should a local user executable be placed (under $HOME)?

Tags: software-installation, executable, directory-structure, non-root-user, fhs

I have an executable for the perforce version control client (`p4`). I can't place it in `/opt/local` because I don't have root privileges. Is there a standard location where it needs to be placed under `$HOME`?

Does the File System Hierarchy have a convention that says that local executables/binaries need to be placed in `$HOME/bin`?

I couldn't find such a convention mentioned on the [Wikipedia article for the FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Also, if there indeed is a convention, would I have to explicitly include the path to the `$HOME/bin` directory or whatever the location of the `bin` directory is?

Comment: `~/.local/bin` – This is the way.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

In general, if a non-system installed and maintained binary needs to be accessible system-wide to multiple users, it should be placed by an administrator into `/usr/local/bin`. There is a complete hierarchy under `/usr/local` that is generally used for locally compiled and installed software packages.

If you are the only user of a binary, installing into `$HOME/bin` or [`$HOME/.local/bin`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is the appropriate location since you can install it yourself and you will be the only consumer. If you compile a software package from source, it's also appropriate to create a partial or full local hierarchy in your `$HOME` or `$HOME/.local` directory. Using `$HOME`, the full local hierarchy would look like this.

- `$HOME/bin`   Local binaries
- `$HOME/etc`   Host-specific system configuration for local binaries
- `$HOME/games` Local game binaries
- `$HOME/include`   Local C header files
- `$HOME/lib`   Local libraries
- `$HOME/lib64` Local 64-bit libraries
- `$HOME/man`   Local online manuals
- `$HOME/sbin`  Local system binaries
- `$HOME/share` Local architecture-independent hierarchy
- `$HOME/src`   Local source code

When running `configure`, you should define your local hierarchy for installation by specifying `$HOME` as the prefix for the installation defaults.

`./configure --prefix=$HOME`

Now when `make && make install` are run, the compiled binaries, packages, man pages, and libraries will be installed into your `$HOME` local hierarchy. If you have not manually created a `$HOME` local hierarchy, `make install` will create the directories needed by the software package.

Once installed in `$HOME/bin`, you can either add `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` or call the binary using the absolute `$PATH`. Some distributions will include `$HOME/bin` in your `$PATH` by default. You can test this by either `echo $PATH` and seeing if `$HOME/bin` is there, or put the binary in `$HOME/bin` and executing `which binaryname`. If it comes back with `$HOME/bin/binaryname`, then it is in your `$PATH` by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So, as per the convention, I can have directories like `bin`, `lib`, `tmp` in my `$HOME`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You certainly can.

Comment: as long as $HOME is not on a noexec mounted filesystem. /tmp/ is usually mounted noexec too.

Comment: This is correct, its part of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS). http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY

Comment: I would not recommend using `$HOME`. This inundates your home directory with numerous directories that you are not interested in at all. Who wants to have `man`, `lib`, etc. in ones home dir? I would rather create the hierarchy below `$HOME/bin` or `$HOME/local`. That adds only one subdirectory to your home dir, instead of ten. The `PATH` can easily be adapted to include `$HOME/bin/bin` or `$HOME/local/bin`.

Comment: Agreed, I wonder why anybody wants to pollute `$HOME` by 10 more directories (in addition to dozens dot-files).

Comment: One option is to use $HOME/.local/{bin,lib,etc.}, as used by e.g. the XDG basedir spec (http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html ) and python (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/ )

Comment: @janneb The *XDG Base Directory Specification* you refer to mentions only `$HOME/.local/share` (Version 0.7, 24th November 2010).

Comment: There's also `$HOME/.local/bin` as used by Python PIP with the `--user` flag.

Comment: agree with Marco and janneb, after 20 years of building software on other peoples machines in my home didrectory. i used to use $HOME/sys alot as a target for ./configure --prefix=$HOME/sys, but nowdays i would probably use ./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local

Comment: What about `~/.local/bin`? Then it wouldn't be splattering directories all over the home folder.

Comment: I go a step further: I configure each local piece of software with a dedicated prefix. It's perfect for software that you try once from source and may not keep. And if you like it do a symlink from `~/bin`. Wrote a script to automate it for autotools and cmake cases: https://github.com/fidergo-stephane-gourichon/source_to_executable_quick

Answer (score 51):

As [uther mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36874/133107), [`/usr/local`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) is intended as a prefix for, essentially, software installed by the system administrator, while `/usr` should be used for software installed from the distribution's packages.

The idea behind this is to avoid clashes with distributed software (such as `rpm` and `deb` packages) and give the admin full reign over the "local" prefix.

This means that an admin can install custom compiled software while still using a distro like Debian.

> ## [From the FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#FTN.AEN1450)
>
> Software placed in / or /usr may be overwritten by system upgrades (though we recommend that distributions do not overwrite data in /etc under these circumstances). For this reason, local software must not be placed outside of /usr/local without good reason.

When installing user-specific software, [uther suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36874/133107) using `$HOME` as the prefix since this ensures you have write permissions. Personally, I feel using `$HOME/.local` to be a more elegant solution, since it avoids cluttering your (hopefully) nice and tidy home directory!

`$HOME/.local/share` and `$HOME/.local/bin` are already used in the [freedesktop.org XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), and distributions are requested to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to the `$PATH`, so it doesn't take much to envision making a `$HOME/.local/lib`, etc, while you're at it.

If you don't really want your prefix to be a hidden directory, you could easily create a symbolic link to it as well, e.g:

```
ln -s .local ~/local
```

---

#### Sidenote

It is worth noting that `.config` (not `.local/etc`) is the default value for [`$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#introduction) used for user specific config files. I should also point out that, unfortunately, a large portion of software ignores the XDG and creates config files wherever they like (usually in the root of `$HOME`). Also note that `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` may be unset if the default `$HOME/.config` is desired.

Oddly, there is no directory reserved for a distribution's default config files, so there is no way to know if a file in `/etc` was supplied by the distro or edited by the system administrator.

Comment: I can't find any mention of `.local` in the FHS

Comment: @DanielSerodio It's in the XDG directory specification, a newer standard that it gaining prominence. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path and https://superuser.com/questions/1170793/why-is-local-share-a-two-level-directory

Answer (score 8):

[The XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) Version 0.8 states local executables should be placed in *~/.local/bin*:

> User-specific executable files may be stored in $HOME/.local/bin. Distributions should ensure this directory shows up in the UNIX $PATH environment variable, at an appropriate place.

If your distro is following the specification you should therefore not have to "explicitly include the path."  This [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316765/343541) tries to ascertain which distributions do this.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like `/usr/local/bin` according to [the Internet website Wikitechy](https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/usrbin-vs-usrlocalbin-on-linux/).

Information about `/usr/bin` from [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRBINMOSTUSERCOMMANDS), they define the folder as the primary directory of executable commands on the system.

Additional information between `/usr/bin` vs. `/usr/local/bin` from [the Wikitechy](https://www.wikitechy.com/technology/usrbin-vs-usrlocalbin-on-linux/):

`/usr/bin` is the location for the OS supplied executables that are used by common users.  For example, not typically core operating system required files, or root user accessed files, but can be.

`/usr/local/bin` is the location for all add-on executables that you add to the system to be used as common system files by all users but, are not official files supported by the OS.

Overall, `/usr/bin` is where binaries supplied by the OS. `/usr/local/bin` is where user downloaded binaries.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is a system directory with root ownership, regular users cannot (and shouldn't if they could) copy their executables into there.

Comment: @thanasisp thanks for the information. Isn't your statement based on assumption of Linux Server case? I don't think if you use your own Linux computer, it won't be prohibited to use `/usr/bin`...Isn't the question from a Linux personal computer user? Please, share some web link regarding personal computer users.

Comment: I assume any computer, on my home pc for example, I have a separated installation of python (different versions) in my `~/.local/` I never touch the system python, it's used by the system, and in general I never use the root account or edit any system directory, unless if I need to do something system-wide, like updating, configuring a service, etc. It's a recommended practice to avoid mistakes also.

Comment: @thanasisp thanks for sharing your practice. I searched the Internet and updated my answer.