# Permissions/ownership of /usr/local/bin

Tags: permissions, directory-structure, fhs

From what I understand, the right place to put your own scripts is `/usr/local/bin` (for instance a script I use to back up some files). I notice that this folder is currently (by default) owned by root, and my normal user has no access to it. I am the only user on this computer. Shall I change this whole folder to my own user? Or is there another proper way to arrange permissions of `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

By default, the owner and group of `/usr/local` and all subdirectories (including `bin`) should be `root.root` and the permissions should be `rwxr-xr-x`. This means that users of the system can read and execute in (and from) this directory structure, but cannot create or edit files there. Only the `root` account (or an administrator using `sudo`) should be able to create and edit files in this location. Even though there is only one user on the system, it's generally a bad idea to change permissions of this directory structure to writable to any user other than `root`.

I would suggest placing your script/binary/executable into `/usr/local/bin` using the root account. It's a good habit to get into. You could also place the script/binary/executable into $HOME/bin and make sure $HOME/bin is in your $PATH.

See this question for more discussion:
[Where should a local executable be placed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed)

Comment: Good answer; I thought maybe I'd add my 2 cents worth.  Even if you are the only user now, this could change in the future, and it's a good idea to follow best practices all the time.  If you have a personal script only for yourself, put it in ~/bin; if it's something others might use, put it in /usr/local/bin.  Others could mean yourself, in a different account, too.  And, remember, some of the rules protect you from yourself, to make it harder to delete important files.

Answer (score 15):

The usual place to put your own scripts is `~/bin`, and then add this directory to your `PATH`.

Comment: I suppose on Arch the preferred location would be ~/.local/bin.

Comment: In Ubuntu these can be added to `~/.local/bin`. The directory wasn't in my path, but once I placed a binary there and rebooted it appeared on the path without having to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are the *only* user on the system, and therefore the only user of the scripts that you write, I don't really see much point in installing personal scripts in `/usr/local/bin`. Installing scripts in `/usr/local/bin` would only make it more awkward to back up and to maintain your personal files.

Also, the `/usr/local` hierarchy may be used when installing external software from locally compiled source code, which means that software installed in that way have a potential risk of overwriting your personal scripts and/or accidentally pick them up as system-provided tools (depending on how you name your scripts).

Also note that package managers on some BSD systems install packages under `/usr/local` (OpenBSD and macOS, for example), which is another reason to leave that particular file hierarchy alone for personal scripts.

If you're the only user of the system, then just install under `$HOME`, for example in a `$HOME/local` hierarchy. Either that, or use a totally separate hierarchy rooted in, e.g., `/opt` or `/sw` or somesuch place (not used by base system or package managers).

Comment: Just because you are the only user doesn't mean it should be in home. Plenty of non-user service accounts/users as a security feature for privilege minimizations. Installing in $home would break that. And that's the entire point of /usr/local/, more so then /opt would be.

Comment: @cde The point of `/usr/local` has to do with separation of locally maintained software from software maintained by the distribution provider. It is not primarily a security feature. Also, exactly how would installing software under `$HOME` _break_ existing services? On systems where service accounts are properly separated for security reasons, chroot jails are used. When a service is chrooted, accessing `/usr/local` isn't possible anyway.

Comment: Because installing in $HOME would mean whatever service OP is using would need to be ran under a user that has permission to access and execute from op's $HOME. So now you have to change group memberships or leave $HOME with more permissive permissions, etc.

Comment: @cde What would be the exact issue with allowing a service account to read files associated with a personal script from your home directory?

Comment: Its kludgy at best and a backdoor at worst.

Comment: @cde So a compromised service account would be less dangerous if it did not have read access to your `$HOME/local/bin` directory? Also, in what way would putting a personal script used by a service account into `/usr/local/bin` not provide a backdoor if putting it under your home directory would? I'm also interested in knowing what type of services you're concerned about.

Comment: Attacker somehow gains access to service account. Service account has access to user's files. No privilege escalation required.

Comment: @cde You would obviously still use sane permissions on files that needs to be protected. That goes without saying in any situation. I'm also still interested in knowing what type of external services you think would reasonable have access to personal scripts in `/usr/local/bin`.