# Accidentally set wrong permissions on /usr

Tags: permissions, directory

I recently created a new mount point /usb to be able to mount USB sticks to my Fedora 32 Linux system and tried to run `sudo chmod a+rwx /usb` on a shell, but accidentally mistyped it as `sudo chmod a+rwx /usr`.

In panic, I thought I had broken my system. I found this post: [Permissions/ownership of /usr/local/bin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37724/permissions-ownership-of-usr-local-bin) and reset the permissions for /usr to rwx for root, r-x for everyone else. Then I rebooted just to make sure, and everything worked OK.

To be safe in the future, what is the worst thing that could happen from accidentally setting the wrong permissions to /usr, and how can I recover from it?

Comment: There is no need to re-boot for file-permissions to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the worst thing that could happen from accidentally setting the wrong permissions

- Someone (that is logged in to your computer) could change system files, then some time later when you run a program e.g. `ls` it does something that it should not.

However not all mode bits are permissions. There can be a few other effects, if done to other files. This could make your system un-usable (or at least make command such as `sudo` un-usable.