# Filesystem organization for software in HOME

Tags: directory-structure, home

When installing software in `$HOME`, how do the linux filesystem hierarchy directories map to subdirectories of `$HOME`?

I am asking this question so that I can write a build system that picks reasonable default paths for a user install.  The build system infrastructure is Haskell-specific (Cabal) but the installed files include C++ headers and libraries, for which Cabal doesn't have a default install path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$PREFIX` is `~/.local/`. Everything else maps under there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a File System Hierarchy (FHS) for package installation in a $HOME directory, it should ideally mirror the FHS of `/usr/local`. See this [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed) for more information and this [documentation](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) on FHS Standards.