# Where should I install manual pages in user directory?

Tags: man

I'm trying to create a Makefile for a small Perl utility I wrote, And I'm struggling to find out a way to find where to install my man page when `make` is run as a **non-root** user.

I'm currently parsing the output of `manpath` to find out the first path in the `$HOME` directory… and it *almost* work fine.

Paths I've found are `~/man` and `~/share/man`

The only problem is that if those directories don't exist in the first place, `manpath` doesn't output any of them.

#### Questions

- Is there a portable way to find out where I should install the man pages in the user's $HOME directory?
- If not, which one of them should be preferred?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put the man pages in this directory:

```
$HOME/.local/share/man
```

#### Accessing directly

And then you can access them directly using `man`:

```
man $HOME/.local/share/man/manX/manpage.1.gz
```

#### $MANPATH

You can check what the `$MANPATH` is with the command `manpath`, or echo out the environment variable `$MANPATH`.

#### Examples

```
$ manpath
manpath: warning: $MANPATH set, ignoring /etc/man_db.conf
/home/saml/apps/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/man:/home/saml/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/share/man:/home/saml/.rvm/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man:/usr/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man

$ echo $MANPATH
/home/saml/apps/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/man:/home/saml/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/share/man:/home/saml/.rvm/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man:/usr/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man:/usr/brlcad/share/man
```

You can add things to the MANPATH temporarily:

```
MANPATH=$HOME/.local/share/man:$MANPATH
```

If you want to make this permanent then add a file in your `/etc/profile.d/` directory called `myman.bash` with the above `MANPATH=` line in it. This will get picked up system wide for everyone. If you want it to be just for you, then add it to your `$HOME/.bash_profile` or `$HOME/.bashrc`.

#### References

- [file-hierarchy — File system hierarchy overview](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html)
- [Which distributions have $HOME/.local/bin in $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path)

Comment: To suppress `manpath` warnings about `MANPATH` being set, you can pass the `-q` option.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can tell to `man` where to look. I'm looking for a generic, portable way for an generic installation (ie: where is `man` looking on a standard configuration)

Comment: Do an `echo $MANPATH` and see what that shows. Those are good places to start looking, or use the `manpath` command as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Where did you get information about `$HOME/.local/share/man`? I could not find any official source for that.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko see here for more - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36874/7453. It's also mentioned here - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed a few apps that I compiled, with the respective `configure`s set for installing in `${HOME}/usr/local`.

I find now that I have directories

```
~/usr/local/share/man/man1
~/usr/local/share/man/man3
~/usr/local/share/man/man5
```

with manpages `gnuplot.1`, `gnuplot-ja.1`, `python3.1`, `python3.5.1`, `libpng.3`, `libpngpf.3`, `zlib.3`, `png.5`, so I guess (given my prefix) it is a pretty standard location for apps installed locally.

It is then a candidate location for the cases where one has to choose manually the local `man` directory.

Of course, one can add arbitrary paths (and should do it even in the usual just case mentioned) for `man` pages with

```
export MANPATH="$HOME/usr/local/share/man${MANPATH:+:${MANPATH}}"
```

(cf. [*The bullet-proof way of Appending/Prepending*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415028/137608) for handling colons `:` in `PATH`).

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer with desciption

I am running Cygwin on Windows 7. When I try

```
echo $MANPATH
```

I get nothing. Here is my portable way of finding where to put new `man` pages.

```
$ { find / -maxdepth 2 -type d -name "*man*" 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | \
grep -v 'Permission denied' >&3; } 3>&2 2>&1
```

(A note on that crazy command is at the bottom of this answer.)

**You could simply replace `/` with `~`.** Another possibility is under the **Another note** section below.

On my machine, the `find` command returned:

```
 /etc/openwsman
 /lib/filemanager-actions
 /lib/gnome-commander
 /lib/help2man
 /lib/window-manager-settings
 /share/man
 /usr/man
```

To me, that meant there were two possibilities: `/share/man` and `/usr/man`.

I chose to use `/usr/man`, which you wouldn't, but I needed to do some more exploring.

```
$ ls -l /usr/man
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 me Users 0 April 31 17:13 man1
```

So, where I had the new `man` files in a `doc/` sub-directory of my working directory, I used

```
$ cp -R doc/* /usr/man/man1
```

Now, I could get to my "manual" by typing

```
$ man my_new_executable
```

If you don't see a likely candidate, you can remove this part or change it, e.g. to `-maxdepth 3`, or `4`, or `5`, or however deep it takes to find what you need. When I did so with `3`, I found two other candidates, `/var/cache/man` and `usr/share/man` , but I had already found a working solution, so I didn't mess with them.

---

#### Another note

I believe that `/share/man/man1` or `/var/cache/man` would be available to non-root users, as you had requested. **Please, correct me if I am wrong.**

---

#### The promised note at the bottom

Note that I used the `-maxdepth 2` option with `find`, because I figured that the `man` directory would be within two directories of the file system root, and I did not want to get too many extraneous directories that somehow had the substring `man`, as did `/lib/gnome-co`**man**`der`.

The extra stuff around the `find` is there to suppress any `Permission denied` errors in case you don't have access to `su` or `sudo`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40336333/6505499) is a great description of what's happening. (Look for the line that starts with "gniourf_gniourf".)