# Where does man bring the pages from? Does it store them? How secure is it?

Tags: man

I'm trying to understand how `man` works. Unfortunately `man man` doesn't yield answers for the following questions:

1. Does the page for a command get installed with it or does `man` bring it from a remote database?
2. If it brings it from the network, then how secure is it? Does it do it over TLS?
3. Does `man` cache the pages locally? If it does, should I clear it on a regular basis?

Comment: What OS's `man` are you using? [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/man.html) explicitly doesn't state where `man` gets manpages from ("The historical MANPATH variable is not included in POSIX because no attempt is made to specify naming conventions for reference page files, nor even to mandate that they are files at all. On some implementations they could be a true database, a hypertext file, or even fixed strings within the man executable.")

Comment: Similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90762/236063

Answer (score 2):

In modern unix-like systems following the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml), the man pages are normally stored in a directory tree located at `/usr/share/man`. Older unix-like systems might use `/usr/man` instead.

Usually `man` does not use network at all, although it's possible that someone somewhere has made a network-based implementation of it.

Commonly, the man pages are written using an old document formatting system originally known as `roff` (its GNU implementation is named `groff`). When viewing a man page, the `man` command will run the man page source code through the formatter, which will produce output tailored to the window width you're currently using. The formatter can also produce PostScript, PDF and possibly HTML renditions of man pages from the same source code, which won't be limited to terminal-style monospaced text.

The `man` command may cache the formatted text versions of man pages as `cat` pages for quicker re-viewing, typically in `/var/cache/man` (FHS) or separate sub-directories of the man page directory hierarchy (older systems). You may find that the system already includes a default (typically weekly) cron job that automatically cleans this cache for you.

If you have the CUPS printing system with the print-to-PDF feature enabled, run `man -t ls | lp -d <name of your PDF virtual printer>` and view the resulting output with any PDF viewer. Or `man -Thtml ls > ls_man_page.html` to get a HTML version. (This is for Debian 10's `man-db` implementation of the `man` command: the formatting options may be different in other implementations.)

Answer (score 1):

> Does the page for a command get installed with it

Yes, it usually does but of course you can always add a new custom manpage to your system without using your local package management system.  You can use your system package manager to learn what package a
given manpage com from.  A big portion of manpages on Linux-based
systems comes from [the Linux man-pages
project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git).

> If it brings it from the network, then how secure is it?

It doesn't but as others said it's possible that someone has written their own implementation that does.  I guess that your confusion might come from the first line in `man man` that says:

```
man - an interface to the on-line reference manuals
```

Or in BSD version:

```
man — display online manual documentation pages
```

See [this LQ
question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/why-man-is-called-on-line-4175495946)
for an explanation.

For fun see also https://explainshell.com.  It's a nice site that can
quickly explain meaning of options in a given command, for example
https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls+-Alhtr but remember that your
local implementation of a given command may differ or may not support
all options (this is especially true when using small Busybox-like
based systems).

And of course `man` can work via network in a sense that you can mount
a remote directory locally and tell `man` to look for manpages there, for
example I can read manpages from the remote FreeBSD machine like that:

```
$ sshfs freebsd:/usr/share/man /mnt/bsd-manpages
$ MANPATH=/mnt/bsd-manpages man man
$ MAN(1)                                                                                

    BSD General Commands Manual                                                                                   MAN(1)

NAME
     man — display online manual documentation pages
```

> Does man cache the pages locally? If it does, should I clear it on a
>     regular basis?

Already well explained in [telcoM's
answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575292/72304).