# Where are you supposed to put user-specific programs?

Tags: filesystems, path, non-root-user, application, multiuser

Say I'm a non-admin user who wants to put an executable somewhere in his path so that he can run it like a regular program.

What is the "proper" accepted location for that path? is it `~/bin`? `~/.local/bin`? Elsewhere?

Comment: I always use `~/bin`, but I don't think there's any kind of standard ... any user is pretty much free to structure his/her home directory however he/she likes.

Comment: Note that while this is a duplicate of that *question*, [the second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264495/73093) is **significantly better** than the accepted answer to it.

Comment: Ahh yup it seems like an exact duplicate. Thanks @MichaelHomer!